# Get value from a file to use in command in Powershell/CMD

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, cmd, terminal

I want to be able to set a version number in a Powershell/CMD argument that is stored in a file.
So let's say i have a long powershell/cmd command that has this argument in it `py -m non_important_script --file-version={*get value from file*}`

How would i get the version number that is stored in a file called version.py with one row of text in it:

```
__version__ = "1.2.0"
```

Basically i don't want to update this argument manually every time. It would be nice if i could always paste the same command into Powershell/CMD and it would put in the version number on it's own.

So far i've tried this `py -m non_important_script --file-version=(Select-String -Path .\version.py -Pattern "\d.\d.\d").Matches.Groups[0].value`, but it doesn't work and gives this error from the non_important_script:

```
FATAL:
Error, specify only one positional argument unless "--run" is specified to
pass them to the compiled program execution.
```

Answer (score 0):

A working Windows CMD solution suggested by Mofi is:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims== " %I in (.\version.py) do if /I "%~I" == "__version__" py.exe -m non_important_script --file-version=%J
```

I managed to figure out a PowerShell solution as well continuing from what I already had in my question hoping there was some easy way to make it work and it turns out there was.

There must be created a variable like this and then end with a semicolon to allow the second command sequence to use the value of the variable:

```
$version = (Select-String -Path .\version.py -Pattern "\d.\d.\d").Matches.Groups[0].value ; py -m non_important_script --file-version=$version
```